# What to do when a user's expertise is so low that they cannot even grasp their own question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've answered two questions to very simple problems, but users are not accepting the answer because their problem comes from a very vague understanding of what they're doing.

Then, what I've tried is to ask the user what they do not understand from the answer, but I've ended acting as a "programming basics" (even "computer basics") teacher.

What should I do, regarding those questions?

Comment: Update: One user finally accepted! but it took me an hour.

Comment: Answering higher quality questions may provide a better experience all around.

Comment: You are conflating a couple of different issues. That other users accepted or not your question is mostly a non-issue. That's a personal choice and there is very little to do about it. What to do about questions where the asker lacks the necessary knowledge to understand the answers? That's not settled. Search around meta and you'll find many heated arguments regarding "helping vs tutoring", the purpose of the site, how welcoming we are to new users, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Why does this get closed as a dupe, with the close target being itself a dupe?

Comment: @IanKemp ... which itself is closed as a dupe of another dupe. It's the nature of dupes to have dupes.